# ASP.NET Grid Editing

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, grid, telerik

I have a query in regards to a Telerik RadGrid in ASP.NET.

I have a basic List(of BusinessObject) that i have bound to a telerik RadGrid
I have enabled the AutoGenerateEditColumn = True and also AllowAutomaticUpdates.

How come it seems so difficult to change a record from a statically bound list from my Grid.

There is a Grid_UpdateCommand Event Handler that allows me to access the changed row by e.Items but i have to cast it to a GridEditableItem instead of my BusinessObject Is this just asp.NET?. Because the record is in memory only i wish to change the value and have the Grid Reflect that value. The tutorials seem convoluted for the task. Im a WPF person myself and find it easy perform this operation in WPF but it just seems crazy that ASP.NET or the Telerik Grid cannot simply change a value of a static record or cast the DataItem as my Custom Business Object.

Please Help

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.Item is a reference to the grid row, not to the business object.  A data bound row is represented by the GridDataItem class, and the edit row by GridEditableItem class.  You can access the class you bound by doing:

```
var obj = ((GridEditableItem)e.Item).DataItem as BusinessObject;
```

As long as you rebound the grid with data, this will work.

HTH.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the quick response Brian. A+++

Comment: Actually the DataItem returns a null value which is strange. Im binding the grid to a list property of public reference to my root business class and page init from a session variable. what would you recommend i do?

Comment: When referencing the item of the row, it could be one of several things: it's the header row for an event that processes each and every row, the data is not yet available when rebound (such as the itemcreated event).  We tap into ItemDataBound and the DataItem property is always given the value.  List shouldn't be OK.  Make sure row processing on data is in ItemDataBound.  Otherwise, give me more details about the code.

Comment: I was trying to access it the DataItem property on UpdateCommand which i now understand will not return a value. Only ItemDataBound will resolve a value for this property. I am going to try and access the value by brute force and use the UniqueColumn header value to resolve the new change of the grid so i can then iterate through or use LinQ expression to update the item in my bound object. I dont see any other way.

Comment: It is exremely easy to do this in silverlight/wpf because when you edit a record in the grid there is event handlers that make it really easy to return the changed value and use this to update the binding source after proccessing some custom business logic.

Comment: Yes, because in Silverlight and WPF, the bound data set doesn't disappear, unfortunately, this isn't an issue with Telerik's ASP.NET controls, but of the stateless web environment (same feature in Microsoft's ASP.NET controls).